# set properties file in shell script

Tags: java, weblogic, properties-file

I have a properties (jdbc.properties) file in "D:\UTL" location that needs to be created and defined in the weblogic startup script. Can someone help quickly ?

I have added  like this which didn't work.

set UTIL=D:\UTL

Do I need to export this variable ?  If yes, I am getting "export is not an internal /external command" error when I'm doing so. Appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0):

If you wanted to export parameters, you can do so in the setDomain.sh. Specify your new variable and set it there in the same format as the previous variables. 
You can do it like
NEW_VAR = "${NEW_VAR}"
export NEW_VAR

if you want to use a emote file, export what you need in the file and in the setDomain, run a `source /path/to/file/file.sh`

If this is application specific and you only want it to load for a particular application startup, please import property file in to application as and when it is required.